# oAuth2.0 implementation

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0

There are two different sites. On the first one is stored username/password (stored in the MySQL database).
On the second one will be implemented oAuth2.0 based on the username/password of the first site.
On the base of the first site, a web service will be developed to verify username / password.
The scheme of work will look something like this:
The user goes to the page of the second site, enters the username / password of the first site and clicks "Login".
After clicking the button, a request is sent from username / password to the verification web service (first site), if username / password is correct, the web service returns a unique user ID.
Do I understand correctly that in order to generate an Access Token it will still be necessary to create a user on the second site (that is not good for security)?

Comment: Please read up on OAuth. You will need some sort of authorization server that handles the authorization process for all your apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say so. This is because either of the sites have no clue about the user of the other. The same user exists as a separate entity in each of them.

However, If the both sites are owned by you, then here is what you can do...

- Get your user to sign into Site2.com
- Post authentication, you will have some identity information from the provider (say google)
- Use the email id to create a session(without login) into the Site1.com
- And the user is not logged into both sites with a Single Sign On :)

OAuth (version irrelevant) covers a larger scope of use cases.

Question is, Why would you use OAuth and have your user log multiple times. Is your site acting like a portal to other apps. That would be nice :), but difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
We don't have Identity Providers such as Google, Facebook.
Site1.com does not support the OpenID standard.
Site1.com can only provide a web service to verify username/password.
As I understand, Site1.com must implement OpenID standard in order to stand as Identity Providers

Comment: If you can explain a bit more on your OAuth scenario I can guide you from there.